# Is it possible to make an exposed filter dependent from a contextual filter?

Tags: views

it seems like it is a trivial and common use case to me, but I have not found a solution so far: I have several vocabularies and I want to deliver a vocabulary via url into a contextual filter and dependent on the vocabulary I want to make the terms of this vocabulary presented as an exposed filter to the user.

As an example: There are vocabularies languages, IT and management, which should be delivered in url and go into a contextual filter. Lets say the delivered vocabulary is languages, then the user should see an exposed filter, where he can choose a language (the terms of the vocabulary) and sees all entities with the chosen terms.

I was looking really intense, but did not find a solution so far.

Thanks in advance